# Incorrect egrep command

Tags: regex, bash, grep, brainfuck

The problem is the following:
I have a document called brain.txt with lines of (brainfuck) code like this:

```
++++++++++[>++++++++>++++++>+<<<-]>+++.>+++++.<-.+.>>. word
```

The `word` at the end can really be any word.
How can i filter the lines from the document where the length of every sequence of < and > is uneven?

I wrote the following command:

```
egrep -v '^(([^<]*(<<)*[^<]*)|([^>]*(>>)*[^>]*))*$' brain.txt
```

But it does not seem to work, can anyone explain me what is incorrect about this command please?

EDIT:
Instead of negating the even ocurrences, i used regex to match the uneven occurences, as Karoly Horvath mentioned. So I wrote the following command:

```
egrep '^(([^<]*<(<<)*[^<]*)|([^>]*>(>>)*[^>]*))*$' brain.txt
```

But for some reason i still match even lines.

Comment: Based on your requirement, I would say that this is not a job for regex. You need a parser.

Comment: @jordanm: No you don't. Perhaps not the best tool, but certainly doable.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath There's a lot of ways that are "doable", but that doesn't make them good ideas. Jordan is suggesting using a different tool that is more appropriate.

Comment: Well, it is meant to be regex, because I am practicing it.

Comment: it's not parsing, it's matching. off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex matches every line where the length of *every* sequence of < and > is *even*.

If you negate it, you will print the rest of the lines - the ones which contain *at least one* uneven sequence.

The other problem is `[^<]` can eat `>`.

Don't negate, just search for uneven:

```
grep -P '^(([^<>]*)|((<<)*<(?!<))|((>>)*>(?!>)))*$'
```